# Merging two columns when column1 is NaN

Tags: pandas

I have df and I want to merge these **2 columns in just 1 column** bringing the values of `value2` to the column `value1` when **value1 is NaN**

```
value1     value2
 100         NaN
 123         NaN
 NaN         133
 NaN         123
 90          NaN
```

How can I get this:

**Expected Output:**

```
Value1
 100         
 123         
 133         
 123         
 90
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
df['Value1'] = df['value1']
df.loc[df['value1'].isna(), 'Value1'] = df['value2']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
out = df.bfill(1).iloc[:,[0]]
```